# Script to delete specific lines from a file

Tags: bash, vim

Is there any way I can delete specific lines from the file?. e.g. I have 8 files that are names as Crest_001.dat, Crest_002.dat, ..., Crest_008.dat. Now I want to delete lines starting from 10 to 30000 from all these files. Right now, I am opening each file manually in vim and using following command: ":10,30000d"

This takes lot of time as my files are huge! Is there any way I can use a script to do this?

Comment: sed -i.bak '10,30000d' Crest_00{1..8}.dat

Answer (score 2):

if your sed supports `-i`, you can use `sed`

```
sed -i.bak '10,30000d' Crest_00{1..8}.dat
```

original files will be backed up with extension `.bak`

otherwise you need to use loop to run `sed` on each file and redirect the output to another filename.

Answer (score 0):

## !/bin/bash

for i in $(find . -name 'Crest*.dat' -print 2>/dev/null)
do
sed -i '10,30000d' "$i"
done